# Creating a pointer to pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I reaslise this is probably quite a noob question but I need to create an array of type 'char**' because that is the type of parameter a function I am using is asking for. After that I need to make every element of that array to be a link. I am open to the possibility that it's not even possible, but so far this is what I tried and as a result got an Access Violation error:

```
char **array[10];
    *array[1] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
    *array[2] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
    *array[3] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
    *array[4] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
    *array[5] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
    *array[6] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
    *array[7] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
    *array[8] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
```

Here's the function in question:

```
Enemytype makeenemy(int hp, int xcor, int ycor, int width, int height, int speed, int a1, int a2, char *imagel[10], char *imaged[10])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    Enemytype m;
    m.width = width;
    m.height = height;
    m.xcor = xcor;
    m.ycor = ycor;
    m.speed = speed;
    m.hp = hp;
    m.a1 = a1;
    m.a2 = a2;
    while (imagel[i]){
        m.arrayl[i] = Loadtext(imagel[i]);
        i ++ ;
    }
    while (imaged[j]){
        m.arrayd[j] = Loadtext(imaged[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return m;
}
```

The point is to create a template with an array of images, without knowing initially how many images it wil hvae. `Loadtext(char* filename)` is the function that creates an image from the given link.
As a result it is asking me for 'char**'.

Comment: your pointers are not initialized… if you need a `char **`, why don't you simply make an array of 10 `char *`s then grab a pointer to its first element?

Comment: Could you show the prototype of the given function ? It seems it requires `char**` and not `char**[10]`.

Comment: This is a question about C, not about C++. I don't see any C++ in your question

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you just have one `*` too many on every line.

```
const char *array[10];
array[0] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
array[2] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
array[3] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
array[4] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
array[5] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
array[6] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
array[7] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
array[9] = ".\\images\\cockroach\\1.png";
```

Comment: if I do that, the function will tell me that 'const char*' is incompatible with 'char**'

Comment: Well, make your other functions const correct. Our stay making copies of your strings. But string literals are readonly.

Comment: typo: `9` should be `8`. and according to the given code `array[9] = NULL`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Not a typo, I was specifically showing the first and last entries in the array (the question used one-based numbering, *shudder*, and I wasn't sure if that was an accident or a misconception).  And the "given code" that looks for NULL wasn't present when I wrote the answer.